# Multi nested quotes

Tags: python

I am generating a command that comprises multi nested quotes and then execute:

```
cmd = "python datax.py -p \"\"\" -Dpsql=\"DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) = \'2019-02-02\'\" \"\"\" "
os.system(cmd)
```

The cmd can be generated as expected:

```
python datax.py -p """ -Dpsql="DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) = '2019-02-02'" """
```

But it seems this does not work well. System still returns exceptions like `'(' unexpected...` etc.

I also tried `'''...'''` and doesn't work either. How to address this issue and is there any other way to deal with this case? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more code, because your cmd snippet runs fine with my python3.7.

Comment: @TobiasK I am using python 2.7.  But when I execute `python datax.py -p .....` it still says `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: Triple-quotes aren't a thing in bash syntax. You're trying to quote shell commands like they're Python.

Comment: @user2357112 Note in general that would be `sh` syntax (`dash` likely) , which is even less rich (poorer?) than `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an escaped backslash `\\` for each nesting level, because your shell most likely does not support triple quotes. Therefore it parses The first two off your triple quotes and `" -Dpsql="` as quoted strings and 
`DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) = '2019-02-02'` as shell code. But `date(yyy)` is not valid shell syntax

An example to reproduce this without having your datax script:

```
cmd = "python -c \"print(\"Hello (world!)\")\""
os.system(cmd)
```

fails with

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

But

```
cmd = "python -c \"print(\\\"Hello (world!)\\\")\""
os.system(cmd)
```

outputs

> Hello (world!)

I suggest to change your code to:

```
cmd = "python datax.py -p \" -Dpsql=\\\"DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) = \'2019-02-02\'\\\"\" "
```

Now your command looks like:

```
python datax.py -p " -Dpsql=\"DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) = '2019-02-02'\""
```

You see, there is an outer quotation level for your `-p` argument and an inner quotation level for the sql code.

Answer (score 1):

If you print `cmd` you get:

```
python datax.py -p """ -Dpsql="DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) = '2019-02-02'" """
```

What `os.system` does is just open a shell with a basic `.sh` interpreter and runs that. Stuff like `"""` are big no-nos for `sh` (mainly because you're not sure what it does - something like an empty string with another start of one) and of course, the parenthesis are also bad for `sh`,

You have to escape or make sure they are in a string. You are going to have to escape everything or make sure a proper `sh` string is passed. This is one way:

```
cmd = r"""python datax.py -p ' -Dpsql=\" DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) =  \\'2019-02-02\\'  \" ' """
```

`r""` conserves backslashes as is.  Printing this results in:

```
python datax.py -p ' -Dpsql=\" DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) =  2019-02-02  \" '
```

A better option I think would be to just use:

```
cmd = r"""python datax.py -p -Dpsql=" DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) =  '2019-02-02' " """
```

So I dropped one level of `'`. Now just fix `datax.py` to parse `argv` to better suite your needs (take everything after the `-p` here). This would make it easier to call it directly as well. When printed:

```
python datax.py -p -Dpsql=" DELETE FROM xxx WHERE date(yyy) =  '2019-02-02' "
```

`argparse` handles these things well.