# Syntax error with os module while using pipe delimeter with jq commnad

Tags: python-3.x, linux, jq, aws-cli

I am using aws-cli command within python `os` module, while using `jq` and output redirection i am getting an error .

**Error:**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**code:**

```
iport os
os.system('aws ce get-cost-and-usage --profile dev --time-period Start=2022-10-01,End=2022-10-31 + 1 month  - 1 second" -I) --granularity MONTHLY --metrics USAGE_QUANTITY BLENDED_COST  --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE | /bin/jq  '[ .ResultsByTime[].Groups[] | select(.Metrics.BlendedCost.Amount > "0") | { (.Keys[0]): .Metrics.BlendedCost } ] | sort_by(.Amount)| add' > /tmp/cost.json')
```

Is there a way to fix it, please let me know.

Comment: You are nesting `'`-delimited strings.

Comment: @pmf, do you know the work around on this.

Comment: The way around: don't nest them. Escape them or use double quotes. This a typo.

Comment: Probably the outer single quotes could be [triple-single-quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings): `os.system('''aws ... | jq '...' ''')`

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017336/multi-nested-quotes

Comment: There are also several alternatives to constructing a shell pipeline. `aws` supports JMESPath, which could let you do the filtering on the remote end instead of parsing the resulting JSON. There is also a `jq` library for Python that lets you filter decoded JSON using `jq` filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @glenn jackman mentioned in the comment section.. you can use `'''` to escape.

I am using below code to send an attachment and HTML view over the e-mail.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import print_function
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
import os
import time
import io
import smtplib
import pandas as pd
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#################################################################
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
#################################################################

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is msg/alternative.
mail_server = 'mail.example.nxp.com'
from_addr   = 'someEmailAddressa@example.com'
to_addr     = ', '.join(['karn.kumar@example.com'])
cc_addr     = ', '.join(['otherAddress@example.com'])
subject     = 'Devlopment Cost Report Seoul'

# Create mail body as template to be send
EMAIL_TEMPLATE = """\
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  table, th, td {{font-size:9pt; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; background-color:LightGray;}}
  th, td {{padding: 5px;}}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     Dear All,<br><br>

     Please Find the attached CSV file attached along with HTML view for the diffrent AW Service cost . <br><br>

     {} <br><br>
    Kind regards.<br>
    Karn
  </body>
</html>"""
# collect the data into Json and save it into a file under /tmp
os.system('''aws ce get-cost-and-usage --profile dev --time-period Start=$(date "+%Y-%m-01"),End=$(date --date="$(date +'%Y-%m-01') + 1 month  - 1 second" -I) --granularity MONTHLY --metrics USAGE_QUANTITY BLENDED_COST  --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE | jq -r '[ .ResultsByTime[].Groups[] | select(.Metrics.BlendedCost.Amount > "0") | { (.Keys[0]): .Metrics.BlendedCost } ] | sort_by(.Amount)| add'  > /tmp/cost.json''')

# Once the data is created now its easy to extract using the pandas.
data = pd.read_json("/tmp/cost.json")
df = (data.T)
df = df.drop('Unit', axis=1)
df.rename(columns={'Amount': 'Amount(USD)'}, inplace=True)


def df_to_csv(df):
    with io.StringIO() as buffer:
        df.to_csv(buffer)
        return buffer.getvalue()

def send_email():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From']    = from_addr
    msg['To']      = to_addr
    msg['Cc']      = cc_addr
    attachment = MIMEApplication(df_to_csv(df))
    attachment['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cost-details.csv"'
    msg.attach(attachment)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(EMAIL_TEMPLATE.format(df.to_html(index=True)), 'html'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server)
    server.sendmail(to_addr, cc_addr, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_email()

# remove the data file from "/tmp" after data parsing.
time.sleep(30)
os.unlink("/tmp/cost.json")
```

**Result is Blow:**
[image]